# Use Three Dots span to trigger DropDown

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap, and have a button with a caret that triggers a dropdown.

[image]

But I need to use the vertical 3 dots instead, not in a button style.

I have a span that uses a CSS class for the three dots, but can't seem to find a way to get rid of the button and caret.

What I have tight now is this:

```
<Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle>
      <span className="threedots"></span>
    </Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu size="sm" title=""> 
      <Dropdown.Header>Options</Dropdown.Header>
      <Dropdown.Item .... ></Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
 </Dropdown>
```

I just want to see the three dots (I'll add a mouse-over effect). Is there a way to use a snap as a toggle>

Comment: the caret is a generated ::after pseudo element. Just give a parent class to the Dropdown, then `display: none` the pseudo element. Similarly, override button styling.

Comment: @Vishal - that sounds good. But I’m not 100% sure how to do the button part. Could you help with pseudo code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can customise Dropdown by passing in custom subcomponents. [Custom Dropdown Components](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/dropdowns/#custom-dropdown-components)

```
const CustomToggle = React.forwardRef(({ children, onClick }, ref) => (
  <a
    href=""
    ref={ref}
    onClick={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      onClick(e);
    }}
  >
    {/* custom icon */}
    {children}

  </a>
));
```

then pass as a custom toggle

```
<Dropdown >
    <Dropdown.Toggle as={CustomToggle}>
    </Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu size="sm" title=""> 
      <Dropdown.Header>Options</Dropdown.Header>
      <Dropdown.Item .... ></Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
 </Dropdown>
```

[sample codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-toggle-react-bootstrap-6iehc),Hope be helpful

Comment: Excellent demo @Alex! If anyone else is wondering how to get rid of the underline on hover, add this to the css file: `.dropdown a:hover { text-decoration-line: none; }`

Comment: in typescript you do ```React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, { onClick: (e: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => void }>(```